# How do you absolutely position elements into a grid layout using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following example shows tiled divs, that once clicked fade out, I have been trying to extend this so a child img is removed instead of the div.

When this happens the div loses any CSS defined width & height and the grid is broken.

Does anyone know how to still animate the image using JQuery UI effects which uses display none and maintain grid layout ?

http://jsfiddle.net/bzCbh/4/ - working example

Thanks

Comment: Is it just me? Where are the images in your example jsfiddle? Also the clicked tiles don't fade out, they just change color. What is the problem actually?

Comment: The problem is when i change it to img tags nested in the divs to disappear, the grid breaks.

Comment: Please add a fiddle that actually demonstrates the issues you are having

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bzCbh/4/ here's the issue

Comment: it seems the best way is to absolute position the divs using javascript instead of CSS using inline / inline-block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tiles are set to `display:inline` which ignores height and width of said element. So it's natural they will collapse when the image is removed, height and width were never respected by the div to begin with. Change them to `display:inline-block` and it'll work.

```
.layer .tile { ... display:inline-block; ...}
```

You should also change the images to `display:block` to make them behave consistently

```
.layer .tile img { display:block; }
```

​
Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bzCbh/7/

Comment: Thanks but i have tried this already - in Chrome & FF it appears as follows: https://adaptive.womworld.com/facebook-tabs/aaaa/img/inline.png

Comment: Are you sure? If you're just assuming, click the link to the Fiddle because it works perfectly on my Chrome & FF...

Comment: I did & it doesn't break in the same way, but the tiles still fall out.

Comment: I Apologise, this worked i didn't realise you had also amended other CSS

Comment: There was an error with your image rendering which lead to some margin problems (no breaking though), that should be fixed now.

Comment: this is great, thanks - it had been bugging me a while, I was sure there was a CSS fix.

Comment: Awesome! One more thing: some of your images are 60px wide and some are 61, might wanna fix that. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Jan - they are just place holders til the final graphics!